# Swift Regex: Replace Lowercase Followed by Uppercase

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have the following string: "HelloMy name is Bob"

I'd like to change it so that any lowercase followed by a capital letter, gets a period in front of it, like this: "Hello. My name is Bob".

Currently, I have this:

```
 var text = "HelloMy name is Bob"
 let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-z][A-Z]")
 text = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count-1), withTemplate: "What do I put here?")
```

However, I don't know what to put in the replacing pattern. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a simple example of using capturing, you may find many articles about it:

```
var text = "HelloMy name is Bob"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([a-z])([A-Z])") //<-Use capturing, `([a-z])`->$1, `([A-Z])`->$2
text = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: text, range: NSRange(0..<text.utf16.count),
    withTemplate: "$1. $2") //<- Use `$1`, `$2`... as reference to capture groups
print(text) //->Hello. My name is Bob
```

---

By the way,`NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count-1)` is not a valid range to use with `NSRegularExpression`. `NSRegularExpression` uses UTF-16 based location and offset. And to represent whole range, `-1` is not needed. Use `NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count)` or `NSRange(0..<text.utf16.count)` as above.

Comment: This only works when brackets () are put around each character in the regex. Could you please explain what these brackets are for?

Comment: In usual regex, non-modified simple pairs of parentheses represents Capture Groups. Each capture group hold the matching substring and you can use reference to capture groups as `$1`, `$2`...respectively. You can find many articles searching with "regex capture group".